# Which endomorphisms of the Tate module of an abelian variety are "algebraic"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

For an abelian variety $A$ over a field $k$ with characteristic different from $\ell$ and Galois group $G = Gal(\overline k/k)$, there is always an injective map of the form:
$$\mathbb Q_\ell\otimes End_k(A) \to End_G(V_\ell(A))$$
where $V_\ell$ is the rational Tate module. In specific cases, we know the map is a bijection ($k$ = finite fields, number fields).

Now suppose we take the direct limit of both sides over increasing $k$. Then the left hand side is simply $\mathbb Q_\ell\otimes End_{\overline k}(A)$ and the map is into $End(V_\ell(A))$ but it's (almost?) never a bijection.

For instance for non super singular curves or in characteristic $0$ and $A$ an elliptic curve, the right hand side is one or two dimensional while the right hand side is four dimensional.

Can we classify or characterize the endomorphisms of $V_\ell(A)$ that are "algebraic", that is, come from the map above for some $k$?

Comment: The limit on the RHS is not $End(V_l(A))$, but rather consists of endomorphisms that are equivariant for some open subgroup of $G$ and, as you say, this is a nontrivial condition e.g. in the case of an ordinary elliptic curve over a finite field.

Comment: Right, I just meant that limit embeds into all endomorphisms and I am interested in what we can say about the image without necessarily using the Galois action.

Comment: My phrasing isn't the best, I guess.

Comment: But as SashaP says, the best/only condition is that they are invariant under an open subgroup of the Galois group.

Comment: For an elliptic curve with CM by an order of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ the LHS is $\Bbb{Q}_\ell [{\scriptstyle\pmatrix{0 & -d \\ 1 & 0}}]$ and the RHS is $M_2(\Bbb{Q}_\ell)$